# XML Schema reference id of complex type

Tags: xml

Suppose I define an XML schema as follows.  Consider a simple User element that has an id, name, email, age, and a set of other Users he/she is friends with.  The friend element would simply hold the id of the User he/she is friends with.  The XML would like something like:

```
<user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Alice</name>
    ...
    <friend>2</friend>
    <friend>3</friend>
</user>
```

I'm struggling to create the corresponding schema.  I currently have the schema below, but because the schema for `friend` is defined as such, I need to include all of the User element nested inside the `<friend>` tag.... which is clearly a bad idea.  How can I change my XML schema to allow for a foreign key reference to another User id?

**Current schema:**

```
<xsd:complexType name="userType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
        [ ... many more fields ...]
        <xsd:element name="friend" type="userType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Why have you set userType as the type of "friend"? Shouldn't it just be int if you only want it to contain the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to allow generic names as ids (instead of integers only), you can take advantage of the `ID,IDREF,IDREFS` [definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-TokenizedType) in XSD. Your schema would then look like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="userType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
        [ ... many more fields ...]
        <xsd:element name="friend" type="xsd:IDREF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However, since these types were originally defined only as attribute types, you may run into problems with certain XSD processors. A version optimized for compatibility and compactness would look like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="userType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        [ ... many fields ...]
        <xsd:element name="friends">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="ids" type="xsd:IDREFS"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The corresponding XML would be

```
<user id="1">
    <name>Alice</name>
    ...
    <friends ids="2 3"/>
</user>
```